# How to suppress callback exceptions in dash 2.10.2 as suppress_callback_exceptions=True is not working?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am a beginner in Dash. I have built dashboard app using Dash 2.10.2, having callback functions as well as background callback functions. (@dash.callback(...))

When I load the page, it intermittently throws errors like - Invalid Value -Unable to Update Figure, but on refreshing it, the outputs are displayed correctly and the error disappears on its own.

To prevent these intermittent errors from happening I have attempted the below 2 ways, but my efforts are futile.

Attempt 1-

```
app=Dash()
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions=True
```

Attempt 2-

```
app=Dash(suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
```

But these are not working. Can anyone please suggest how to prevent these intermittent exceptions in my callbacks and background callbacks, so that the app works smoothly for my stakeholders when they use it?

Edit - Adding code snippet

```
df=pd.read_csv(....)
dropdown=dcc.Dropdown(options=subjects,value=subjects[0])
dropdown2=dcc.Dropdown(options=another,value=another[0])
app.layout=html.Div(children[
   dropdown2,
   dropdown,
   dcc.Store(id='intermediate-value')
   dcc.Graph(id='graph1'),
   dcc.Graph(id='graph2'),
   dcc.Graph(id='graph3')
]
)

@dash.callback(
Output(component_id='graph2',component_property='figure'),
Input(component_id='dropdown2',component_property='value'),
manager=background_callback_manager
)
def f2(selection):   # intermittent error occurring at updating this figure 
                           # on starting app
 #some code and processing
return fig2

@app.callback(
Output('intermediate-value','data'),
Input(component_id='dropdown',component_property='value')
)
def heavyProcessing(selection):
 filtered=df[df[x]==selection]
#heavy processing
return processed.to_json(date_format='iso',orient='split')

@app.callback(
Output(component_id='graph1',component_property='figure'),
Input('intermediate-value','data')
)
def f1(data):
#some code
return fig1

@app.callback(
Output(component_id='graph3',component_property='figure'),
Input('intermediate-value','data')
)
def f3(data):    # intermittent error occurring at updating this figure on 
                     #starting app
#some code
return fig3
```

Intermittent error generally occurs at fig2 (1st callback) and fig3 (last callback).

Comment: Did you fully restart the app or did you let the dash hot reload do the job? Also, have you tried using the `prevent_initial_call=True` callback argument?

Comment: This is happening both at full restart and hot reload, and happening seldom, not everytime. Also I have not used prevent_initial_call=True anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error description

> Invalid Value -Unable to Update Figure

I think you should actually handle the error instead of trying to suppress it.

My guess is that certain input values are not handled well by your callback(s).

To track this down you can inspect your browser's network tab and see what requests fail and what input values are used in these failing requests.

---

`suppress_callback_exceptions` also doesn't suppress all errors that might happen inside a callback.

> suppress_callback_exceptions: check callbacks to ensure referenced IDs exist and props are valid. Set to True if your layout is dynamic, to bypass these checks. env: DASH_SUPPRESS_CALLBACK_EXCEPTIONS

https://dash.plotly.com/reference

```
app = Dash(suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
  html.Div(id="input"),
  html.Div(id="output"),
])

@app.callback(
  Output("output", "children"),
  Input("input3", "children"), # Nonexistant id, would be suppressed
)
def func(input_value):
  return input_value
```

```
@app.callback(
  Output("output", "children"),
  Input("input", "children"),
)
def func(input_value):
  x = 1 / 0 # Can't divide by 0, won't be suppressed.
  return input_value
```

Comment: This error "cannot update figure - invalid value" is occurring seldom when I start or reload app and not every time. If there had been anything wrong in the callbacks, then it would have failed every time.

Comment: No not necessarily. Based on the information you've shared that's not clear. Really depends what you're doing exactly inside the callbacks. However you could be experiencing this bug https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3441.